# Overridden Thread.start() but confused (Two Scenarios)

Tags: java

It's quiet right that we should never override the start method of a thread but I was just practicing java when I was confused with two different behaviors.....
I'm trying to override start method of Thread class.Below is the code:

```
package myPackage;

public class MainThreadUsingThread extends Thread{  
    @Override  
    public void run() {  
        System.out.println("-run   in t1");  
        System.out.println("");  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void start() {

        System.out.println("in start in t1");
        super.start();
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hii");
        Thread t3=new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread());
        t3.start();
    }*/
}

class A11 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        System.out.println("hii");  
        Thread t1=new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread());  
        t1.start();
        Thread t2=new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {  
                System.out.println("run in t2");  
            }  
            @Override
            public void start() {

                System.out.println("in start in t2");
                super.start();
            }
        };
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

In case of Thread "t2", I'm getting the overridden start method but not in case of Thread "t1".
Plz help me come out of this confusion.

Also is there any way to do the same (override, as far as it is not a good practice) in case of runnable interface.

Comment: Your last question is not clear.

Comment: You have a type in thread 1 - it also says "in start in t2"? I assume that is wrong?

Comment: Subclassing Thread is a good way to confuse yourself.  The number of ways this can result in strange behaviour means it is considered bad practice.  You would implement a Runnable and wrap it with a Thread (or pass it to an ExecutorService)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Thread t1=new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread());
```

Your `new MainThreadUsingThread()` is being used as [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) (because `Thread` implements `Runnable`). The thread executes `Runnable.run()`, that's why you don't get the overriden `start`.

When `Thread.start` is called, it starts a new thread and call `Thread.run` in that new thread.

You should do this:

```
Thread t1=new MainThreadUsingThread();
```

In `Thread`, its `run` method starts the `Runnable` that is used to construct that `Thread`, or does nothing if no `Runnable` is used to construct it. If you extends `Thread` and override `Thread.run`, this effectively changed what the thread does.

If you use `new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread())`, this effectively call the constructor [`Thread(Runnable target)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) and constructs a new `Thread`. Just like doing this:

```
Thread t1=new Thread((Runnable)(new MainThreadUsingThread()))
```

Comment: Thanks @Alvin for your quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 4):

When you write:

```
Thread t1=new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread());
```

you are using your `MainThreadUsingThread` object as a Runnable, not a Thread (Thread implements Runnable), and its start method is never called.

If you write:

```
Thread t1 = new MainThreadUsingThread();
```

You should get what you expect.

Comment: Thanks @assylias for your quick and helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `Thread t1=new Thread(new MainThreadUsingThread());` and t1 is not an object of `MainThreadingUsingThread`. It just calls the `start()` method of the new `Thread` and it then calls the `run()` method of `MainThreadUsingThread`.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your second question:

It is not best practise to extend the Thread class.  Rather use the Runnable interface, i.e.

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
   }
});
```

Of course, this is not the best approach, either.  I really recommend that you have a look at the ExecutorService.  This contains stuff such as pooling, so that new thread is not created every time.  You simply submit jobs and they get done.

It also supports stuff like Futures, which makes for very elegant code, if used correctly.